# Prevent Eclipse from opening multiple tabs in Chrome

Tags: eclipse, google-chrome

I am developing a Hibernate Spring application using Eclipse which is configured to use Chrome as the external browser. Every time I `right click on project > Run As > Run on Server`, Eclipse loads the home page in a new tab in the Chrome browser. This results so many tabs opening in the browser and makes it clumsy and cluttering. How can I restrict Eclipse (or Chrome) to use the existing tab in Chrome browser every time running the project?

(I checked both in Eclipse and Chrome preference settings, but no success. I try to configure Google search results settings as well, still no success)